# Контент в зависимости от выбранных select

Tags: html, javascript

Здравствуйте.
У меня есть форма с несколькими select. По сути, меня из нее интересуют всего 2 select, в которых выбираются свойства, в зависимости от которых мне нужно отобразить информацию в соседнем div. В соседнем div отображается iframe, где источником является адрес вида:   `/s1099/m/2/300/500`, где нужные параметры идут после буквы m. Двоечка - это, по сути, значение из первого списка, а вот далее 2 цифры - это крайние значения из второго списка.

Помогите сделать так, чтобы при выборе сначала значения из первого списка показывались все предметы этой категории (для этого вторые параметры должны быть 0 - 9999), а уже при выборе значения второго списка оставалось нужное.

Форма (выдержка):

```
<select>
    option id="sel1">1</option>
    <option id="sel2">2</option>
    <option id="sel3">3</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option id="rad1">150 - 300</option>
    <option id="rad2">300 - 500</option>
    <option id="rad3">500 - 999</option>
</select>
```

Пытаюсь приспособить этот скрипт, не получается:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sel').change(function(){
        var chosen_radio=$(this).attr('id');
        if (chosen_radio == "rad1") {
            $("#result").html("<iframe src='http://site.ru/m/2/0/9999' height='400' width='100%' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>");
        } else if (chosen_radio == "rad2") {
            $("#result").html("<input type='hidden' name='type' value='Ищу водителя / исполнителя'>");
        } else if (chosen_radio == "rad3") {
            $("#result").html("<input type='hidden' name='type' value='Ищу водителя / исполнителя'>");
        } else if (chosen_radio == "rad4") {
            $("#result").html("<input type='hidden' name='type' value='Отдам заказ / Ищу исполнителя'>");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/epxy43hL/ 
Вот вам работающий пример для определения нужных вам событий по `change`, надеюсь, поможет правильно настроить логику.

Answer (score 0):

Читай [ТУТ](http://www.php.su/substr) и [ТУТ](http://www.php.su/str_replace)